# Chart.js using the value of certain data in external json file

Tags: javascript, html, json, chart.js

I'm working on this self exploration which I want to show a chart that shows how many anime that have comedy genre or fantasy genre. The data for my chart is going to be an external json file (anime.json) on my computer and it's not yet contain the total of how many anime that have comedy or fantasy genre, so I need to do some loop to know that. I try this to make it happen by trying with this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>

<script>
    let data;
    $.getJSON("anime.json", function(json){
            data = json;
            });

    let comedy = 0;
    let fantasy= 0;
    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
    {
        let genres = data[i]['genres']
        for (j = 0; j < genress.length; j++)
        {
            let value = genres[j].trim()
            if (value.toLowerCase() == 'comedy')
            {
                comedy = comedy +1;
            }
            if (value.toLowerCase() == 'fantasy')
            {
                fantasy = fantasy + 1;  
            }
        }
    }

    let myChart = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');

    let massPopChart = new Chart(myChart, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels:['Comedy', 'Super Natural'],
            datasets:[{
                label : 'Genre',
                data: [
                comedy,
                superNatural
                ],
            }]
        },
        options : {},
    });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

But when I open this html on my browser, It came up empty so I'm wondering what is the correct way to do it. And this is my json file (and I have like 25 or 30 of them):

```
[
{
    "cover_title": "Haikyuu!! TO THE TOP",
    "cover_studio": "Production I.G",
    "cover_img": "https://s4.anilist.co/file/anilistcdn/media/anime/cover/large/bx106625-UR22wB2NuNVi.png",
    "format": "TV",
    "duration": "84%",
    "description": "The fourth season of Haikyuu!!\n\nThe Karasuno High School Volleyball Club finally won their way into the nationals after an intense battle for the Miyagi Prefecture Spring Tournament qualifiers. As they were preparing for the nationals, Kageyama is invited to go to All-Japan Youth Training Camp. At the same time, Tsukishima is invited to go to a special rookie select training camp for first-years in Miyagi Prefecture. Hinata feels panic that he\u2019s being left behind as one of the first-years and then decides to show up at the Miyagi Prefecture rookie select training camp anyway...\n\n(Source: Crunchyroll)",
    "genres": [
        "Comedy ",
        " Drama ",
        " Sports"
    ]
},
{
    "cover_title": "Eizouken ni wa Te wo Dasu na!",
    "cover_studio": "Science SARU",
    "cover_img": "https://s4.anilist.co/file/anilistcdn/media/anime/cover/large/bx109298-YvjfI88hX76T.png",
    "format": "TV",
    "duration": "79%",
    "description": "First year high schooler Midori Asakusa loves anime so much, she insists that \"concept is everything\" in animation. Though she draws a variety of ideas in her sketchbook, she hasn't taken the first step to creating anime, insisting that she can't do it alone. The producer-type Sayaka Kanamori is the first to notice Asakusa's genius. Then, when it becomes clear that their classmate, charismatic fashion model Tsubame Mizusaki, really wants to be an animator, they create an animation club to realize the \"ultimate world\" that exists in their minds.\n\n(Source: Crunchyroll)",
    "genres": [
        "Adventure ",
        " Comedy"
    ]
},
{
    "cover_title": "Made in Abyss: Fukaki Tamashii no Reimei",
    "cover_studio": "Kinema Citrus",
    "cover_img": "https://s4.anilist.co/file/anilistcdn/media/anime/cover/large/bx100643-fPH9OgEKKvcI.jpg",
    "format": "Movie",
    "duration": "78%",
    "description": "Dawn of the Deep Soul continues the epic adventure of plucky Riko and Reg who are joined by their new friend Nanachi. Together they descend into the Abyss\u2019 treacherous fifth layer, the Sea of Corpses, and encounter the mysterious Bondrewd, a legendary White Whistle whose shadow looms over Nanachi\u2019s troubled past. Bondrewd is ingratiatingly hospitable, but the brave adventurers know things are not always as they seem in the enigmatic Abyss...\n\n(Source: Sentai Filmworks)",
    "genres": [
        "Adventure ",
        " Fantasy ",
        " Sci-Fi ",
        " Drama"
    ]
}]
```

Thank you!

Comment: When you `console.log(genres)`, is it has data?

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be fine, the only thing I can see is you are not handling the callback properly. The code you have written after `$.getJSON` should be placed inside the callback function. As because of the async behavior your data is set after other codes are executed. If you open `console` you may see error as `cannot read property length of undefined` as initially, the data is undefined.

Below snippet should fix your problem.

```
<script>
$.getJSON("anime.json", function (json) {
  const data = json;
  let comedy = 0;
  let fantasy = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    let genres = data[i]["genres"];
    for (j = 0; j < genress.length; j++) {
      let value = genres[j].trim();
      if (value.toLowerCase() == "comedy") {
        comedy = comedy + 1;
      }
      if (value.toLowerCase() == "fantasy") {
        fantasy = fantasy + 1;
      }
    }
  }

  let myChart = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");

  let massPopChart = new Chart(myChart, {
    type: "bar",
    data: {
      labels: ["Comedy", "Super Natural"],
      datasets: [
        {
          label: "Genre",
          data: [comedy, superNatural],
        },
      ],
    },
    options: {},
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: hello, thank you for your solution but it still shows a blank white page when i open it in browser